# Loading Varying Number of files with Ajax

Tags: ajax

I have an HTML page that dynamically loads one to many HTML snippets that are used as modal forms on the page.  The page comes out of a CMS, so the business users can decide "I want one form on this page" or "I want 6 forms on this page".  Each of the links and it's loading info need to be a module that goes together and can be put on any page.  When each of these links are chosen on the page, I'm outputting a snippet of code that will call an Ajax load script when the page loads.

Snippet Example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{   
load('/web_fragments/file.html', 'content_item1');  
$('#item1').click(function(){               
    $('#rmi_item1').dialog("open");        
    return false;    
}); 
$('#rmi_item1.modal').dialog({autoOpen: false, modal:true, 
  dialogClass:'modal', width:590});}); 
</script>
<a href="#" id="item1">Request More Information</a>
<div id="rmi_item1" class="appLvl mod modal dialog">
<div id="content_item1">
</div>
</div>
```

Each of the IDs and divs on the page have unique identifiers, I've just simplified them here for ease of reading.  The problem is the load method.  I have no idea how many of these will be on the page, so I can't really create multiple load methods.  If there is only one item on the page, it all works great. Here is the load method I have now.  I'm new to Ajax/jQuery, so I extend my apologies and beg you to be kind!  :)

```
function load(url, target)
{
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = ' Fetching data...';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (req != undefined) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {targetDiv(url, target);};
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send("");
    }
}

function targetDiv(url, target)
{
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // only if req is "loaded"
    if (req.status == 200) { // only if "OK"
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or help is welcome as I am now officially about really to lose my mind over this error!  Thanks!

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions?  I'm at the end of my project and the end of my rope!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from this line

```
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Here you use (and implicitly declare) a variable req. This variable is declared in the
global scope (window object)

Make this var local to the load function, like this

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

This will prevent the second snippet to overwrite the req var and trash the first
snippet request that was just fired but not yet recieved.

Have a look to the jquery load method. This should make your code smaller and avoid
this problem.

hope this helps,

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info.  I tried making the req a local variable, but it didn't work.  I'm definitely going to look into the jQuery load method and see if that will help.